# Issue with Arbiter feature compatibility after upgrade of replica set of two nodes with Arbiter to 3.6

Tags: mongodb

I have upgraded MongoDB replica set to 3.6 following this instruction https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-replica-set/. When I executed command

```
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )
```

both Primary and Secondary updated feature compatibility to 3.6, but Arbiter feature compatibility remained 3.4.

Why it remained 3.4 and how to make Arbiter have same feature compatibility as Primary as Secondary?

Comment: At a guess, it's because feature compatibility version only affects the _data_ ; and because an arbiter doesn't store any data, that flag isn't relevant to it?

Comment: @VinceBowdren sounds sensible, but I was not able to find any confirmation for that. Maybe there is actually nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MongoDB 3.6.7 arbiters continuously log "Using sessions while not fully upgraded to FCV3.6" even though replset is FCV3.6](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-37049):

> Arbiters always have the downgrade value of FCV, regardless of the FCV of the replica set. So if the arbiter has binary version 3.6, it will always have FCV=3.4. They never learn the FCV, since they do not replicate the admin.system.version collection. Arbiters' behavior is not allowed to depend on FCV for this reason.